# SubApplication uses parent application path

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote i simple tool which load some configuration:

```
stream = new StreamReader("configuration.xml");
```

As stand alone it works, but when I start it like procces they looking `configuration.xml` file in parent application path. Is it normal behavior?

```
C:\My simple Tool\tool.exe 
C:\My simple Tool\configuration.xml

C:\ParentTool.exe
```

And as subproccess of `ParentTool.exe` the `tool.exe` application is looking for `configuration.xml` in `C:\` but not in `"C:\My simple Tool\"`, as I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried placing both the sub-application and its configuration file in the same directory as the parent application?

Comment: Yes, this is normal behavior.  When you pass in a relative path (like "configuration.xml"), it will look for the file in the same directory that that the current program is currently executing in.  That's standard not just for .NET, but for web sites, DOS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing:

```
stream = new StreamReader("configuration.xml");
```

To:

```
stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\My simple Tool\configuration.xml");
```